# Find all $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in which $x^2+2$ divides $x^5-10x+12$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring

> Find all $n\ge2$ such that $x^2+2$ divides $x^5-10x+12$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

To begin, I divided $x^5-10x+12$ by $x^2+2$ which gave me:
$$x^5-10x+12 = (x^3-2x)(x^2+2)-6x+12$$

So, I guess I need to find $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in a way that $-6x+12$ is congruent to $0$, right? But I have one question before it. Can I just care about $-6x+12$ and don't care when, for example, $x^2+2$ will be congruent to $0$ in some $\mathbb{Z}_k$? For example, if I pick $\mathbb{Z}_6$ I get what I desire, but what about $\mathbb{Z}_2$? I wouldn't be dividing by $x^2+2$ anymore because it is $x^2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Also, will the answer be every $\mathbb{Z}_{2k}$?

Comment: $6=0\implies 12=0$, so all you need is $6=0$, that is, $n\mid 6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}_2$ we have $-6x+12=0$, so indeed $x^2+2$ divides $x^5-10x+12$. The fact that $x^2+2=x^2$ is more or less irrelevant. The polynomial $x^2+2$ is monic, so your division is correct in all $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ with $n\ge 1$.

The answer will not be all $\mathbb{Z}_{2k}$. For example, $-6x+12$ is not the zero polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$, and indeed is already non-zero in $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{6k}$ right?

Comment: No, $-6x+12$ is not the zero polynomial in, for example, $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. Think small.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: Also $\mathbb{Z_2}$. And there could be a case made for $\mathbb{Z}_1$, for there both polynomials are the zero polynomial.